# Invalid enterprise token androidmanagement .net, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using android management api in using c# i have issue in my code, what i am doing wrong with code? It's showing INVALID ENTERPRISE TOKEN issue.

```
        string serviceAccountKeyPath = "./client_secrets.json";
        string projectId = "dark-hal";

        // Authenticate using service account credentials
        GoogleCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountKeyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                         .CreateScoped(AndroidManagementService.Scope.Androidmanagement);
        }

        // Create the Android Management API service
        var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "YourAppName"
        });

        SignupUrlsResource.CreateRequest signupUrlRequest = service.SignupUrls.Create();
        signupUrlRequest.ProjectId = projectId;
        signupUrlRequest.CallbackUrl = "https://www.yahoo.com";
        var signupUrl = signupUrlRequest.Execute();

        string enterpriseToken = signupUrl.Url;
        Console.WriteLine("Signup: " + enterpriseToken);

        EnterprisesResource.CreateRequest createRequest = service.Enterprises.Create(new Enterprise());
        createRequest.ProjectId = projectId;
        createRequest.SignupUrlName = signupUrl.Name;
        createRequest.EnterpriseToken = enterpriseToken;
        var enterprise = createRequest.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Signup: " + enterprise.Name);
```